# How can I solve this error that happens while building my angular application?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, sass

When building my angular application I get an error on the sass-loader.

I tried updating the sass-loader dependency but it didn't work.

Can someone help me?

Below all the info

OS: Windows Server 2016 build 14393

**Angular Version:** (ng --version)

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 11.7.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.11.4
@angular-devkit/core         7.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.1.4
@schematics/angular          7.1.4
@schematics/update           0.11.4
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.1.6
```

**Node version:** v11.7.0

**NPM version:** 6.5.0

**Stack ERROR:**

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (67)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.9.3
    at module.exports (C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.sassLoader (C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:72)
    at runLoaders (C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:286:20)
    at C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:364:11
    at C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:230:18
    at runSyncOrAsync (C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:143:3)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:229:2)
    at C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:4
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:38:13)
    at processResource (C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:199:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:158:10)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:173:18
    at loadLoader (C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:36:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:173:18
    at loadLoader (C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:36:3)
ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (67)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.9.3
    at module.exports (C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.sassLoader (C:\WebService\mipaaf\mipaaf-fe-2\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:46:72)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mipaaf-fe@0.0.0 build: `ng build --prod`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mipaaf-fe@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin.daniele.isoni\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-24T16_52_35_999Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would like to add this as a comment, but don't have enough points.
Have you tried `npm rebuild node-sass` ? I had this error before and running this fixed it